# Embedding latest youtube video into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WP theme, which was working last I check and has since stopped. Maybe it's something little but it's driving me nuts right now.

I'm taking a youtube username and grabbing the latest video and embedding into the page. Seems to be pretty simple, but I may be attacking it wrong.

Here is my code(any suggestions?):

```
                        <?php // Get YOUTUBE FEED
                    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

                    // Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source. - YOUTUBE FEED ADDRESS
                    $youtube = fetch_feed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads');
                    if (!is_wp_error( $youtube ) ) { // Checks that the object is created correctly
                        // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 1.
                        $maxitemsy = $youtube->get_item_quantity(1);

                        // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
                        $rss_itemsy = $youtube->get_items(0, $maxitemsy);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <h3>YouTube</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php if ($maxitemsy == 0) echo '<li>No Video? Check out our <a href="http://www.youtube.com/USERNAME" >YouTube Channel</a></li>';
                        else
                            // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
                            foreach ( $rss_itemsy as $item ) {
                            $link = $item->get_item_tags('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'player');
                            $useThis = $link[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <object style="height: 172.5px; width: 230px">
                                    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo getYTid($useThis);?>">
                                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                                    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo getYTid($useThis);?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="230" height="172.5">
                                </object>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <?php echo $item->get_content();?>
                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
```

Anyways, I keep getting the "No video, check out our..." output instead of the youtube embed (which was showing up before).

Help!

Comment: Is fetch_feed your own function or is it from SimplePie?

Comment: Wordpress actually uses SimplePie/has it built in. Fetch_feed is a wrapper for the simplepie class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a var_dump of $youtube and $maxitemsy? I'm guessing that something went wrong with the fetch_feed call and ath causes your $maxitemsy to be either 0 or undefined.

Comment: That's correct :( for some reason $youtube isn't existing... no idea why. The feed exists and other feed calls are fine. I'm stumped

Comment: Can I please see the real URL you're using? Right now the username is "USERNAME." Maybe there is something funky about the feed?

Answer (score 0):

I know this happened about a year, but i find a solution using the code in the question so i'd like to share it.

I think the problem is the way you're retrieving the data reading the rss.

You should replace the line when you use get_item_data for

```
$link = $item->get_item_tags('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'group');
$media_content = $link[0]['child']['http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']['content'];
$youtubeFullUrl = $media_content[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
```

and with $youtubeFullUrl you can embed the object.  This will have "http://youtube.com/v/...." stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```
$videoId = $item->get_item_tags('http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015', 'videoId');

echo '<iframe width="425" height="239" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' .
     $videoId[0]["data"] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Comment: Please explain your answer